# Scikit learn spam mail prediction code always predicts the same result

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

The code: spam mail prediction

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


raw_mail_data=pd.read_csv("mail_data.csv")

mail_data=raw_mail_data.where( (pd.notnull(raw_mail_data)),"" )



mail_data.loc[mail_data["Category"]=="spam","Category"]=0

mail_data.loc[mail_data["Category"]=="ham","Category"]=1


X=mail_data["Message"]        
Y=mail_data["Category"]       

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, 
                                                    Y, 
                                                    test_size=0.2,  
                                                    random_state=42)


feature_extraction= TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words="english",lowercase="True")




X_train_features=feature_extraction.fit_transform(X_train) 
X_test_features=feature_extraction.transform(X_test) 




Y_train=Y_train.astype('int')
Y_test=Y_test.astype('int')


model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train_features,Y_train)



prediction_on_training_data=model.predict(X_train_features)
accuracy_on_training_data=accuracy_score(Y_train,prediction_on_training_data)
print("Accuracy on training data:",accuracy_on_training_data)



prediction_on_test_data=model.predict(X_test_features)
accuracy_on_test_data=accuracy_score(Y_test,prediction_on_test_data)
print("Accuracy on test data:",accuracy_on_test_data)



inputs=input("please type a message.")

input_mail=[str(inputs)]

input_data_features=feature_extraction.transform(input_mail)

print("input_data_features:",input_data_features)

prediction=model.predict(input_data_features)
print("prediction:",prediction)

if prediction[0]==1:
   print("Normal mail",prediction[0])
elif  prediction[0]==0:
   print("spam mail",prediction[0])
else:
   print("unknown condition")
```

Even though I enter spam mail content as input (discount etc), I can't get a result of 0. (ie spam mail) The code cannot guess correctly. It always gives 1 result. What is the reason for this? The accuracy scores look normal (%96) for the train and test set.  Does a mistake in the writing of the code cause the same result over and over? or should i try another algorithm like decision tree ?

Comment: You have high class imbalance. Use better algorithm.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a different opinion on your problem. Spam class is about 13% in the overall dataset, which is more than enough for training purposes and is likely common in spam detection problems.

The first and main issue you have is a lack of data preprocessing. I've gone through your dataset and there are lots of spelling errors, which add to character count, and even words that clearly render the entire email as spam are often spelled differently (FreeMsg, WINNER!!), which means they will be encoded as different by an algorithm. You need to apply a lemmatizer and remove punctuation characters.

Secondly, I would use cross-validation to check for results on the model with a stratified k-fold, which takes care of class imbalances instead of a random train/test split. Another option would be to under/oversample your dataset but that would produce the same result with considerably more work.

Please try those two suggestions before looking up other classifiers. Logistic regression should be capable of resolving this fairly easily

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using accuracy for model evaluation, you should use a measure that works well with class imbalance.

Have a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html

If you average the accuracy per class, then also classes with a small amount of samples will be optimized.

Using only accuracy the best thing your classifier can learn is to always say: No spam. (Because after all, most of mails are not spam.)